# how to get a full list of windows "view installed updated" using Get-WmiObject as its appears in control panel

Tags: powershell

hey team i am trying to extract a list of my windows updates (not only hotfix) using powershell. when running Get-HotFix i am getting only the Microsoft HF IDs list and not the list you can view in the Control Panel.

any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I retrieve update information from local/remote workstations using the ComObject `Microsoft.Update.Session` to retrieve update history.

```
function Get-UpdateInformation
{
    param
    (
        $ComputerName
    )

    $ScriptBlock = {
        $UpdateSession = New-Object -ComObject Microsoft.Update.Session
        $Search = $UpdateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher()
        $History = $Search.GetTotalHistoryCount()
        $Search.QueryHistory(0, $History) | Select-Object Title,Description,Date,@{N='Operation'; e={
            switch($_.Operation)
            {
                1 {"Install"}
                2 {"Uninstall"}
                3 {"Other"}
            }
            }
        }
    }
    $CommandSplat = @{ScriptBlock = $ScriptBlock}

    if($ComputerName)
    {
        $CommandSplat.Session = New-PSSession $ComputerName
    }
    Invoke-Command @CommandSplat
    if($CommandSplat.Session)
    {
        Remove-PSSession $CommandSplat.Session
    }
}
```

Run it either as `Get-UpdateInformation` or `Get-UpdateInformation -ComputerName Computer`

If you want to explore all the properties available, change this line

```
$Search.QueryHistory(0, $History) | Select-Object Title,Description,Date,@{N='Operation'; e={
```

to

```
$Search.QueryHistory(0, $History) | Select-Object -ExcludeProperty Operation -Property *,@{N='Operation'; e={
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you...

```
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate 
Get-WUHistory
```

Comment: thanks do you know if there a way to achieve that with out of the box command vs external modules ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not.  I haven't found any other way at least.